# Anime where a boy gets a white beam blasted at his arm which eventually turns him into a white alien creature

Tags: story-identification, anime

I only saw a small clip of it, but this teenage boy gets a white beam blasted at his arm. At first only a scar stays but then it turns into a gem. He covers it up and sometime his arm swells up and gets way deformed and muscular. There’s a scene where a lady wraps it up and stabs it and then it goes normal. But finally it’s too much for him and he fully transforms into a white alien creature.

I don’t know the name but it’s not *Teknoman*. The only thing I remember from the name is that it has a very unusual name.

Comment: When did you see it? Was it in English? Where did you see it?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232810/anime-boy-transforms-into-whiteorange-being-after-a-terrorist-attack (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

[Bounen no Xamdou (Xam'd: Lost Memories)](https://myanimelist.net/anime/4177/Bounen_no_Xamdou)

To quote the short summary:

> Sentan Island is a small island surrounded by the Yuden Sea. It exists in a state of dreamlike tranquility, cut off from the war between the Northern Government and the Southern Continent Free Zone. Our hero, Akiyuki Takehara, lives on Sentain Island along with his mother Fusa. He is currently separated from his father, the town doctor Ryuzo, but the bond between father and son remains. One day, after taking Ryuzo the lunch that Fusa has made for him as usual, Akiyuki arrives at school, where he is caught up in an explosion along with his friends, Haru and Furuichi. The explosion produces a mysterious light, which enters Akiyuki's arm, causing him excruciating pain. He's given no time to understand it, however, as the white-haired girl who rode on the bus with him guides him to a power unlike anything he's ever known.

As you mentioned, he gets hit with a white light. Not mentioned on MyAnimeList is that this light leaves a gem on his arm as well. In the end

> Akiyuki completely transforms into a Xam'd

Here's a picture of the white alien creature:

[image]