# Anime: boy transforms into white+orange being after a terrorist attack

Tags: story-identification, anime

Typical Japanese style anime art, it was a series.

- It has been around for more than 6 years.
- I think it mixed fantasy and sci-fi. It was certainly not Isekai and it has no magic, it feels more like revered science.
- A boy gets a gem embedded into his arm after a terrorist attack and transforms into a white and orange humanoid being.
- There are more people able to transform into these beings.
- There is also a red flying ship with a dark yellow underbelly that throws boxes with parachutes.
- There is also this top-secret laboratory where the scientists study how to battle against the beings.
- There are some other flying ships of varying colors.
- If I remember correctly, the protagonist gets amnesia near the end of the plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Xam'd: Lost Memories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xam%27d:_Lost_Memories)* (2009)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1300170/):

> A young man named Akiyuki is a victim of a terrorist attack perpetrated on his peaceful island during wartime. As a result of the attack, he is imbued with an indefinable entity known as a Hiruko and becomes Xam'd. Akiyuki is unwillingly endowed with great powers and must learn to live in symbiosis with the Hiruko. If he does not, the Hiruko will take over his soul and turn him to stone. Akiyuki's family and friends become intertwined in the war which is raging between the northern and southern islands of their homeland.

You can see the attack and transformation in the trailer:

---

Found by remembering having seen it asked for on this very site.

Comment: That was my first thought

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking for this anime since 3 years ago.